# Compiling SciPy and UMFPACK with Intel compiler on Linux

Tags: scipy, umfpack

We're aiming to compile SciPy (and UMFPACK) with the Intel Compiler to
use Intel's (multi-threaded) MKL BLASs, having already done this
successfully for NumPy.  With the help of various websites, we've
achieved this for UMFPACK and SciPy without any apparent error
messages. However, we suspect that the resulting SciPy is
not finding our UMFPACK and instead is silently using much slower
alternative functions (SuperLU).

Could anyone help us with (a) how to determine whether SciPy is
finding our UMFPACK, and (b) how to point SciPy,
whether at the compilation or execution stage, to our UMFPACK library?

Comment: would you mind sharing details on how you got the NumPy compilation to work? I've been at it for several days, and still can't successfully `import numpy as np; np.test()`...

Comment: These instructions worked for me http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl. In site.cfg be sure to edit the path to your Intel MKL installation if it is not at the default location. Also, I am using numpy-1.7.0 and found that it was not necessary to edit intel.py.